# How to create a post-rename or post-delete event hook for CKFinder?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

I need to edit content and inform the user about various things if a file is deleted or renamed inside CKFinder. I thought I could create a JavaScript solution and then offload the logic into the backend with some simple AJAX, with something like this:

```
CKFinder.on('successfulFileRename', function(event, oldpath, newpath) {
    // Contact backend, see where file was used, inform user etc etc
});
```

But alas, I could not find any event system. How would I implement this functionality for CKFinder? Events I need are File/Folder - Rename/Delete/Move. It doesn't have to be a frontend solution, but I would prefer it for simplicity. My backend is ASP.net MVC3.

*(Alternatives for CKF are welcome as comments, but they need about the same functionality as it has.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/) I was also not able to find any event like extension points.

However looking through some of the source I've found the [`sendCommandPost` metho](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.dataTypes.Connector.html#sendCommandPost)d on the `CKFinder.dataTypes.Connector` which gets invoked every time when somethings needs to be send to the server. So on every important event like File/Folder - Rename/Delete/Move.

So you can easily create a custom plugin where you can access the [CKFinderAPI](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinderAPI.html#constructor) instance and from there you can override the `sendCommandPost` and add you custom logic

```
CKFinder.addPlugin( 'myplugin', function( api ) {
    var orginalsendCommandPost = api.connector.sendCommandPost;
    api.connector.sendCommandPost = function() {

      // call the original function
      var result = orginalsendCommandPost.apply(this, arguments);

      // commandname as string: 'CreateFolder', 'MoveFiles', 'RenameFile', etc
      console.log(arguments[0]); 
      // arguments as object
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments[1]));

      return result;
    }
} );
```

And registering the plugin:

```
config.extraPlugins = "myplugin";
var ckfinder = new CKFinder( config );
```

Comment: Sounds great, I'll give it a spin and report back here.

Comment: I actually tried it just now and at least at the frontend level it's very, very good. Still working on the backend and I haven't tested it for every possible scenario, it is exactly like what I wanted. Excellent and simple solution.